# Extract items which appears for all articles occurence

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have following table as below:

Structure:

```
ArticleId INT, 
Name varchar(100), 
NameId INT
```

Sample data:

```
ArticleId    Name    NameId      
----------------------------
1            a       100
2            a       100
3            a       100
2            b       200
4            a       100
1            c       300
4            g       400
1            h       500
2            h       500
3            h       500
4            h       500
```

I would like to get only those `Name`s and their `NameId`s whom appears among all articles (`ArticleId`). As given above we have `ArticleId`s: 1,2,3,4. Names `a` & `h` pass the criteria because only them appearing in all articles. From the other hand `b,c and g` appears only in given articles (not for all).

In the end, the result should be:

```
a       100
h       500
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: You have a serious normalization issue here: either `Name` or `NameId` should be in another table `Names` and there should be another table `Articles` with a list of all possible `ArticleId`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using aggregation we can try:

```sql
SELECT Name, NameId
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY Name, NameId
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ArticleId) FROM yourTable);
```

Actually, the above only works if you're certain that every article ID would appear at least once in the table.  It would be much better to assert the count of articles from a table dedicated to holding aritcles, so:

```sql
SELECT Name, NameId
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY Name, NameId
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM articles);
```

Comment: Of course there could be situation that certain articles doesn't exist in my table because no Names was added yet (maybe in future they will) nevertheless i am only intrested what exactly now in my table. In that case ur first query will be fine right?

Comment: Yes, in that case the first query should be OK.